# React Native How to fetch data from other collection firestore Flatist

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

i do flatlist from firestore and it can use only one collection but i have 2 collection
collection1 is users that store avatar , email , name. collection2 is posts that store image , text ,timestamp, uid but i want my feed have collection post and user, avatar from collection users like this
users [ avatar , email , name ]
posts [ image , text , timestamp , uid ]

and my code Fire.js i try to use data from collection users to collection posts but it error

```
addPost = async ({text, localUri}) => {
        const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri, 
`photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}`)
        //const user = await 
firebase.firestore().collection("users")
        //const PostName = user.name
        //const PostAvatar = user.avatar
  
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.firestore.collection("posts")
            .add({
                text,
                uid: this.uid,
                timestamp: this.timestamp,
                image: remoteUri,
                //postname: PostName,   // error 
                //postavatar: PostAvatar
            })
            .then(ref => {
                res(ref)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                rej(error);
            }); 
        });
    };
```

Post.js to handle text and image to fire.js

```
handlePost = () => {
        Fire.shared
            .addPost({ text: this.state.text.trim(), localUri: 
this.state.image})
            .then(ref => {
                this.setState({ text: "", image: null });
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Feed");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error);    
            });
    
    };
```

Feed.js to do Flatlist

```
useEffect(() => {
            const subscriber = firebase.firestore()
              .collection('posts')
              .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                const users = [];
      
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  users.push({
                    key: doc.id,
                    name : doc.data().name, //want name from collection users but it can't
                    text : doc.data().text,
                    timestamp : doc.data().timestamp,
                    avatar : {uri:doc.data().avatar}, //want avatar from collection users  but it can't
                    image : {uri:doc.data().image}
                
                  });
                });
          
                setUsers(users);
                setLoading(false);
              });
```

And it not show name and avatar in app just show only from collection posts

i learn from yt and i don't know how to do.
what should i do, Can i use two collection in flatlist or copy user and avatar from collection users

Sorry if i use wrong grammar, i'm not good at english. Hope you help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to asking questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Comment: Also, no links please, include code in your question. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Lastly, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: i edit, without photo thank you so much